# PHP putting four dates in an array from a while loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, php-carbon

Using the below while loop, I get four dates in the echo, which is what I need.

```
$data = [];

$start = Carbon::createFromDate('2016', '04', '01');
$end = Carbon::createFromDate('2017', '04', '01');

while($start < $end)
{
    $data[] = $start;

    echo $start;

    $start->addMonths('3');
}
```

Output:

```
2016-04-01
2016-07-01
2016-10-01
2017-01-01
```

But when I dump the $data[] array, I just get four collections, each with the same date:

```
2017-04-01
```

What am I doing wrong? I just want to put the above four dates in an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning an object instance ($start) to each array entry (and objects are "by reference"), and modifying that object instance, so the same object instance is being changed wherever.... assign a "clone" into your array

```
while($start < $end)
{
    $data[] = clone $start;
    echo $start;
    $start->addMonths('3');
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's it, thanks a lot for clearing that up for me, didn't know :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do this

```
echo $start;

 $start =   $start->addMonths('3');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not creating the array properly.

```
`$data = []`
```

Should be

```
`$data = array();`
```

Comment: Short array syntax is perfectly valid in modern PHP (Modern being >= PHP 5.4.0, ie since March 2012)